# Total Busy time metric in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

In the results of the simulation I have total Busy time of node[0] is 2.32E-4 and total Busy time of node[4] is 0.003802 , what does it mean "E-4" . Is this time in seconds or milliseconds?
My goal is to sum these two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`E-4` means `0.0001` so `2.32E-4 = 0.000232`. Time is in seconds.